# Como inserir um contador de tentativas dentro de uma exceção (except ValueError) do Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá. Eu sou iniciante em programação e venho tentando desenvolver por conta própria programas que aprendi em exercícios de livros de programação. Eu fiz minha versão do clássico "Guess the number", onde o usuário tem (n) tentativas para acertar um número gerado aleatoriamente pelo programa. Meu problema está no contador de tentativas. O contador que coloquei (5x) só abrange no caso de usuário acertar digitando somente números, ou errar as 5 tentativas. Porém, há um validador de entrada. Se o usuário digitar uma letra, o validador entra em um loop e só sai se ele digitar um número, e dentro desse loop eu não consegui inserir um contador. Minha pergunta é: Como eu posso contar os caracteres inválidos como número de tentativas?

```
Variáveis usadas:
x = contador de tentativas
t = número de tentativas final
n = número digitado pelo usuário
r = número aleatório gerado pelo módulo random
```

Código do programa:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    #coding=utf-8
    #Filename=num.py

    # Importa os módulos necessários
    import random
    import time

    # Define uma linha vazia
    def vazio():
        print()

    # Define uma linha pontilhada
    def linhas():
        print('----------------------------------------------')

    # Define três pontinhos
    def pontinhos():
        print('.')
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(0.3)

    # Define o título    
    def title():
        print('##############################################')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('#################### NUM #####################')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('##############################################')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        pontinhos()

    # Define a introdução
    def intro():
        nome = input('\nQual é o seu nome? ')
        vazio()
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\nOlá %s!\n' % nome)
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\nEu estou pensando em um número...\n')
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\nEntre 1 e 100...\n')
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\nAdivinhe qual...\n')
        linhas()
        time.sleep(2)

    # Define o main loop 
    def main():
    """ Adivinhe o número aleatório de 1 a 100  com no máximo 5 tentativas """

        title()
        intro()
        x = 0
        n = 0
        t = 0
        r = random.randint(1,100)
        while True:
            # Se errar ou acertar...tente novamente ou saia do jogo...
            if x == 5 or n == r:
                # Se errar
                if x == 5 and n != r:
                    print('\n5 tentativas não foram suficientes! :(\n')
                    linhas()
                # Errando ou acertando...
                x = 0
                t = 0
                r = random.randint(1,100)
                s = input('\n[S] para sair: ')
                linhas()
                vazio()
                if s == 'S' or s == 's':
                    pontinhos()
                    print('Agradeço por jogar NUM!')
                    break
                else:
                    title()
            # Verifica se números são digitados ao invés de letras...
            while True:    
                try:
                    n = int(input('\nDigite um valor: '))
                    vazio()
                    pontinhos()
                    linhas()
                    break
                except ValueError:  # Se digitar letra ao invés de n....
                    linhas()
                    print('\nIsso não é um número!\n')
                    linhas()
            # Se acertar        
            if n == r:   
                print('\nVocê acertou em %d tentativas! :)\n' % t)
                linhas()
                time.sleep(1)
            # Se o número digitado for menor que a resposta...
            elif n > r:
                print('\nO número é menor que isso!\n')
                linhas()
                time.sleep(1)
            # Se o número digitado for maior que a resposta...
            elif n < r:
                print('\nO número é maior que isso!\n')
                linhas()
                time.sleep(1)
            x = x + 1
            t = t + 1

    # Chama o main loop
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, parabéns pela iniciativa na programação. A sua versão do código está bem organizada e comentada. Isso é uma boa prática de programação.

Como você está iniciando e está criando sua própria versão do problema, alterei o seu código minimamente. Com o tempo você vai ver aonde pode melhor e otimizar seus programas.

Para que os inputs errados do usuário contem como tentativas, adicionei a variável `maxTentativas` que vai se tornar verdadeira ao atingir o máximo de tentativas permitidas e irá impedir que o código entre na parte de testar o número depois do `while`. Removi sua variável `x` e deixei somente a `t`, pois assim não há mais a necessidade da primeira.

A variável é inicializada antes do primeiro `while`:

```
n = 0
t = 0
maxTentativas = False
r = random.randint(1,100)
```

E também quando entra em nova iteração o jogo. Aqui a sua variável `x` foi substituída por `t`.

```
if t >= 5 or n == r:
    # Se errar
    if t >= 5 and n != r:
        print('\n5 tentativas não foram suficientes! :(\n')
        linhas()
# Errando ou acertando...
t = 0
maxTentativas = False
r = random.randint(1,100)
s = input('\n[S] para sair: ')
```

O seu contador de tentativas é adicionado no `except` e, logo após incrementá-lo, há um teste para ver se atingiu o máximo de tentativas. Caso verdadeiro ele atualiza a variável `maxTentativas` sai do `while`. Depois, se o jogador atingiu o máximo de tentativas, não há a necessidade de testar se ele acertou o número ou não. Assim, o `if` após o `while` impede que esses testes sejam realizados.

```
# Verifica se números são digitados ao invés de letras...
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('\nDigite um valor: '))
        vazio()
        pontinhos()
        linhas()
        break
    except ValueError:  # Se digitar letra ao invés de n....
        linhas()
        print('\nIsso não é um número!\n')
        linhas()
        t = t + 1
        if t >= 5:
            maxTentativas = True
            break

if not maxTentativas:
    # Se acertar
    if n == r:
        print('\nVocê acertou em %d tentativas! :)\n' % t)
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
    # Se o número digitado for menor que a resposta...
    elif n > r:
        print('\nO número é menor que isso!\n')
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
    # Se o número digitado for maior que a resposta...
    elif n < r:
        print('\nO número é maior que isso!\n')
        linhas()
        time.sleep(1)
    t = t + 1
```